# access hard disk after booting DOS

Tags: dos, disk

I recently made a floppy that boots MS-DOS 6.22. It boots successfully, but then I can't access the hard drive. It can access the floppy drive and CD optical drive, but not the hard disk.

I first tried making a floppy by downloading from www.allbootdisks.com.  Then I tried making a floppy from bootdisk.com. Both have the same problem.

What should I do to access the hard disk? Do I need a driver?

Comment: Is your hard disk formatted? If so, what file format does it use? How big is the disk? How big is the partition(s)? DOS only supports partitions formatted as FAT. It cannot read, for instance, more recent formats such NTFS, ext4 or anything like that. Also the max partition size is 2GB.

Comment: The disk has a partition formatted with FAT16.  That is the one I want to access.  It is size 502 MB.  It has its own drive letter (F:).  There are other partitions on the disk with NTFS, but I don't want to access those.

Comment: I have a different boot floppy made by Windows XP that boots into a DOS-like environment.  After booting with it, I can access the F drive.  But I now want to boot into true DOS.

Comment: How far "in" on the disc is this partition? IIRC you need to have it not too far away on a large disc. Also, what does fdisk see about the partitions?

Comment: The FAT16 partition is the second one on the disk, after the partition for windows which is 22 GB.

What FDISK shows does not make sense.  The info doesn't match what's on the disk.

Dmdiag /v (launched from windows) shows correct partition length 526,385,664 bytes and partition type 0x06 (FAT16b).

Again, I have a boot floppy made by Windows XP that boots into a DOS-like environment.   After booting with it, I can access the FAT partition.

The FAT16 partition is a logical drive contained in an "extended partition." I will try making it a "primary partition."

Comment: I made it a primary partition, but it still cannot be accessed from DOS.  The partition type is now 0x0E which means "WIN95: DOS 16-bit FAT, LBA-mapped."

Answer (score 2):

From your comments:

> "It has its own drive letter (F:)"

...actually drive letter config is specific to instance of the O/S you're running under. A partition does not have an intrinsic drive letter. That may be the letter your disk is mapped to in Windows, but it doesn't mean anything outside that context. Under Linux for instance, the same partition would be mapped an entirely different way, because Linux has no no concept of drive letters. Equally if you have two versions of Windows installed on a PC you could have the same physical partition mapped as F: on one install and G: on another.

So under DOS your partition is not necessarily mapped to the same (or any letter). According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_letter_assignment#Order_of_assignment it will map each readable partition automatically in the order it detects it. So it might be C: or D:, maybe. So you need to check and see if it's been mapped to another letter.

Of course it's also possible it may not actually detect the disk at all. Drives installed via SCSI or SATA will probably require extra drivers. You may have a hard time finding a SATA driver in particular, since this technology didn't exist when MS-DOS was current. If your BIOS supports it, try putting the disk into IDE emulation mode and hopefully DOS can then detect it. You may lose a bit of performance, but at least you can access the disk.

Comment: You're right about the drive letter. It's F only when running Windows.  When I booted with the pseudo DOS floppy, it's C.  So I was aware.

When I booted with the true DOS floppy I looked for all drives A thru Z.  The only valid ones were the floppy and the CD optical drive.

My disk is IDE PATA.  So I need advice.